# Ubuntu vsftpd create user with access to one directory but restrict ssh access

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ftp

I've created a user `ftp_user` and then i restricted its access to `/var/www/html/folder`. It worked just fine but then i found out that i could connect trough `ssh` using Putty with that `ftp_user` and its password.

Reading a little bit i came across some articles and one of them suggested to use this command:

```
root@server:~# usermod -s /sbin/nologin ftp_user
```

The problem is that after using this command when i try to connect trough ftp i'm getting this error:

```
530 Login incorrect.
```

So i did a little bit of research and came across an article that suggested to use this two commands:

```
root@server:~# usermod -s /etc/shells ftp_user
root@server:~# usermod -s /bin/false ftp_user
```

But i still get the `530 Login incorrect`. response.

I'm using a digital ocean vps that runs `Ubuntu 14.04.1`.

Comment: Do you HAVE to use FTP?  This is 2018.  SCP is much better and easier.

Comment: a tech support asked me for access trough ftp so ... not my choice, i would use ssh anytime :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that in order for the chroot to work you need to have a valid shell.
If you really need the chroot you can block access via ssh and password with this option in the openssh config file:

```
DenyUsers ftp_user
```